# No response from the UDP server

Tags: c++, sockets

I am not an expert in C ++ nor in socket communication.

I need to connect to a server and this server should respond to my request with an XML format stream.

I have created the client (inspired by other programs) with which I try to connect to the correct IP address and port by sending a RTSP call. The connection seems to be fine, but the problem is that when I run `recvfrom()` I don't get any data. I tried to make a UDP client and `recvfrom()` returns -1.

This is the code of the UDP client:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
 
    WSADATA data;
    WORD version = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wsOk = WSAStartup(version, &data);
    if (wsOk != 0) {
        cout << "can't start winsock!" << wsOk << endl;
        return;
    }
    //create a hint structure for the server
    sockaddr_in server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    inet_pton(AF_INET, "192.0.0.1", &server.sin_addr);

    //socket creation
    SOCKET out = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    // write out to that socket
    
    string s = "rtsp://pluto:paperino@192.0.0.1/media.amp?video=0&audio=0&event=on";
    
    int sendOk = sendto(out, s.c_str(), s.size() + 1, 0, (sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(server));
    
    if (sendOk == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cout << "That didn't work!" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "connection from server is ok: " << sendOk << endl;
    }
    int len = sizeof(server);
    char buffer[1024];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    int recOk = 0;
    
    recOk = recvfrom(out, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0, (sockaddr*)&server, &len);
    if (recOk != SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Receive response from server: %s\n", buffer);
           
    }
  

    //close the socket    
    closesocket(out);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: Use Wireshark or tcpdump to see what's going on on the network

Comment: When a winsock call returns -1, you need to call WSAGetLastError to see what the actual error was.  What does that return when the recvfrom call fails?

Comment: thanks for you reply. As you can see on the listed the WSAGetLastError is called when the sendTo is called, and after that I haven't errors, the variable sendOk give me exctly the characters sent to the server. The problem is after when I call the recvFrom() and I receive  -1 , I've tried to call WSAGetLastError after the recvFrom() and the error is 10054

Answer (score 1):

In comments, you say that `recvfrom()` is reporting error `10054`, which is `WASECONNRESET`.  The [`recvfrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom) documentation on MSDN says the following about that:

> | Error code | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | WSAECONNRESET | The virtual circuit was reset by the remote side executing a hard or abortive close. The application should close the socket; it is no longer usable. **On a UDP-datagram socket this error indicates a previous send operation resulted in an ICMP *Port Unreachable* message.** |

In other words, you sent your request to a port that is not listening for UDP messages.  Which makes sense, as you sent your request to port 80, which is typically used for HTTP traffic over TCP, not RTSP traffic over UDP.

For that matter, what you sent wasn't even a valid RTSP request to begin with.  I suggest you read up on how the [RTSP protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7826) actually works (hint: you don't send a `rtsp://` URL with it).